# Mock the CGI.HTTP_REFERER using Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, http-referer

I am trying to write some search engine optimized code for a Coldfusion project, and one thing I am trying to accomplish in that is changing a few page variables when the page is referred from different search engines.

Does anyone know if there is a way, or if it's even possible to mock the CGI.HTTP_REFERER to Google, Bing, Yahoo, etc??

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616980/how-do-you-spoof-http-referer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your method, instead of using CGI scope directly, use an argument, e.g.:

```
<cfargument name="cgiScope" type="struct" default="#CGI#" require="false">
```

Done. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is frowned upon to show different kind of content for search engine bots. Either way, it is not possible to change the CGI.HTTP_REFERER with Coldfusion. Your best bet is to edit your "hosts" file and add an entry to point google.com to the IP of your server (eg. 127.0.0.1) and set up a page with a link to your site to fake the request as coming from Google/Bing/Yahoo.

Comment: Since spiders typically don't report the referrer, this likely would not affect them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the CGI scope is large in part determined by what's sent in a request's headers. The referer in particular is easily spoofed. See the following:

1. [Ben Nadel explains how to with CFHTTP and CFHTTPPARAM to spoof the referer](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/903-Passing-Referer-AS-ColdFusion-CFHttp-CGI-Value-vs-HEADER-Value-.htm).
2. [Firefox Plugin Modify Headers](http://modifyheaders.mozdev.org/) (my comment points an answer with this).

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function getHttpReferer that normally returns CGI.HTTP_REFERER, however when you unit test you can mock out that function to return whatever you want.